# storing / reading and checking if a user has read blog posts

Tags: php, mysql, database, mobile, foreach

im building a blog style CMS for learning and want to re do a feature.

Currently, if you view a blog (and are logged in) a cookie is set with the time of the viewing and also the id of that blog.

On the home page, blogs are echoed out using a foreach loop.

There is a check made that looks for a cookie matching the blogs id, and if there is a match then it checks the time of the cookie to that of the late time the blog was updated.

If there is a match, it can also detect if the user read that blog.

This works, but my practice is a for a mobile focussed site, and cross device this just wont work. I need it to have continuity for the users.

My idea instead is to have a database table laid out as

```
ID, blog_id, user_id, view_date
```

Then when showing all the blogs i can refer to this table and keep the same stats across devices. Now the questions is...

To do this i would need to a foreach, in a foreach. This isnt recommended i know but i cant remember how to do it other wise?

Also lets say hypothetically, i have 1000 users, who have all viewed 20 blogs. Thats a table with 20k rows.

Is that an issue? Checking that database for every blog?

Or am i being paranoid and php / DB is more powerful than i think?

Or... is there a better way around this?

Comment: When you have 1000 users with 20 blogs each **and** have some issues with such an enormous size - come back and ask about it.

Comment: its not 20 blogs each, its 1000 users who have viewed 20 blogs each. I dont think thats an enormous projection. Also this is mainly for learning and interest about understanding. Unless this is a bit for in depth / confusing than its worth putting the effort in for until then?

Comment: if it's about learning - then read about normalization and design your schema to fit the 3NF requirements.

Comment: "To do this i would need to a foreach, in a foreach. This isnt recommended i know" --- it's a misunderstanding. There is nothing wrong with "foreach in foreach". If only you mean what you've said

Comment: i dont know why you need a foreach in a foreach

Comment: sorry, i would be checking a table called blogs, and then in the foreach for that table, be checking the table that stores the view data. And come to think of it, that query wouldnt need to be a foreach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: You are a bit paranoid, 20k rows is nothing for a MySQL database.

The longer answer: What you do need is:

1. a proper index on the table since you have to do lookups. Assuming you're amount of users always exceeds the amount of (viewed) blogs, it's best to create an index on `blogId, userId`, so you will only have to look through just a few records.
2. a proper query, like:

> ```
> SELECT
>     view_date
> FROM
>     tableBlogView
> WHERE
>     userId = #fill in userId# AND
>     blogId = #fill in blogId#
> ```

This way you don't need foreach in for each and such